# Master Chief Collection keeps on crashing - Fatal Error

Tags: ubuntu, steam

Trying to launch Master Chief Collection through Steam on my Ubuntu setup. I've tried it to force over the following Proton versions:

- Proton-5.0-GE-1
- Proton-4.21-GE-1
- Proton-4.11-11

I've also tried to repair the EAC with wine.

Whenever I try to run it I select the disable EAC option. I get a 'fatal error' every time. The game seems to be running fine for other people. Anyone a clue what the cause could be?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. It turns out that to use Proton with Steam there are some extra steps that need to be done first that I had missed. You can see the requirements for Proton here: https://github.com/ValveSoftware/Proton/wiki/Requirements

In my case, I have Intel graphics and I had to run these commands in order for the game to work:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kisak/kisak-mesa
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo apt install mesa-vulkan-drivers mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386
```